# Is "bite down a towel" idiomatic?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idiomatic-language

Looked up the dictionary, and it seems there's no entry for the phrasal verb "bite down", so it's not a common usage; however, there are a few entries for "bite down a towel" on Google. I also used a colloquation dictionary and it doesn't appear there either.

For example:

> He bit down a towel in anger.

The question is what "bite down" means exactly? I thought it meant "bite hard into", but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Bite down *on* a towel" is possible. If a person has had a tooth extracted, and they are bleeding in their mouth, they might put a towel in their mouth and bite down on it to stop the bleeding. It is not exactly a common expression, but a dentist might say it.

"Bite down on something" means to hold something tightly in your teeth. If you bite down on a piece of wood, you would leave tooth marks.